# JsessionId is not dispalying in the url?

Tags: java, session, spring-security

I converted my spring-security.xml from 3.2 to 4.0. If I continue with 3.2 then JsessionId is displaying. When comes to 4.0 it is not showing JsessionId.With that I am not able to restrict multiple logins with the same user(concurrency-control).

This is my configuration in **Spring-security.xml**:-

```
<security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login" session-fixation-protection="newSession" >
   <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/login"/>
</security:session-management>
```

I used same code as aboue for both spring-security-3.2 and 4.0.
How can I get JsessionId.

Answer (score 2):

In Spring 4.X url-rewriting was switched to disabled by default meaning the JSESSIONID is managed by cookies rather than the URL.

If you need it back in the short term you should be able to set: disable-url-rewriting="false"

source:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-http-disable-url-rewriting

**edit**
Spring have disabled this functionality intentionally as OWASP list it as 'broken Authentication and Session Management' You should consider using cookies combined with the spring security session control functionality:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-concurrent-sessions